# Create dictionary of lists by object feature

Tags: python, arrays

Lets say I have a class:

```
class Cat(object):
     color = "White"     # "Black", "Red" or whatever
     name = "..."
     ....
```

If I have a list of cats, I want to separate them by color and put in dictionary of lists:

```
cats = [cat1, cat2, cat3, ...]
cats_by_color = {"White": [cat1, cat3, ...], "Black": [...], ...}
```

Now I do it like:

```
cats_by_color ={}
for cat in cats:
    if cat.color not in cats_by_color.keys():    # add new key if needed
        cats_by_color[cat.color] = []
    cats_by_colors[cat.color].append(cat)        # add cat to right list
```

And I have a strong feeling that there is a "more pythonish way" of doing such things. How to do it by some one-liner?

Comment: this `if cat.color not in cats_by_color.keys():    # add new key if needed
        cats_by_color[cat.color] = []` can be replaced by a `default_dict`, for starters

Comment: there is `itertools.groupby`, too, but it requires a sorted list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it in a one-liner, you'd need to sort the list first, then use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from operator import attrgetter
from itertools import groupby

color = attrgetter('color')
cats_by_color = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(cats, key=color), color)}
```

However, sorting is more costly than just a straight loop; this is no longer a one-liner, but using [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) at least makes it compact:

```
from collections import defaultdict

cats_by_color = defaultdict(list)

for cat in cats:
    cats_by_colors[cat.color].append(cat)
```

Here `defaultdict` will create a new `list` object for keys that are not yet in the dictionary, merely by trying to access the key.

Comment: @mgilson: you missed the other typo in the post though. :-P (no closing parenthesis on the `groupby()` call).

Comment: How about `(lambda d={}:[d.setdefault(c.color,[]).append(c) for c in cats] and d)()` for a no-import 1 liner.

Comment: Ick, a list comprehension for the side-effects! Where are my holy symbols and garlick!

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to get it into a true 1-liner -- And this was the only way I could come up with.  But anyway, my real point was to just use the defaultdict... No need to bring an O(nlogn) algorithm into this just to fulfill some silly "1-liner" requirement.  I go back and forth on this one, but when I'm real with myself, I think that answering "give me a 1-liner" questions literally is not the best thing for the language -- It gives the perception that 1-liners are better than multi-liners as opposed to striving for good, idiomatic python.

Comment: @mgilson: I agree; I was including an explanation as to why it is not a good idea in the answer.

Comment: I like the defaultdict solution.

Comment: Yes. I think that the readability of defaultdict is better (one see what happens in one glance) and it is OK-liner for the task. 

But it is interesting how to make it 1-liner at least for curiosity too. (Update. I put my +1)

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import defaultdict
cats_by_color = defaultdict(list)

for cat in cats:
    cats_by_colors[cat.color].append(cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it in one line, without any imports:

```
cats_by_colors = {color: [cat for cat in cats if cat.color == color] 
                  for color in set(cat.color for cat in cats)}
```

However, as this iterates over all `cats` for each `color` (and once to get the colors) it is not very efficient!

Note that your `Cat` attributes are currently *class*, not *instance* attributes, it should be:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, color, name):
        self.color = color
        self.name = name
```

Comment: Holy exponential list iterations! You do realize that you are now looping N squared times, right?

Comment: Only if every cat has a different color... I will note that although this is neat it is not efficient!

Comment: The `set()` production is a full `N` iteration, then a subset of N iterations are executed times a full loop over `N` again. Not quite N squared but far from efficient.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I would expect that, even as the number of cats got very large, the number of discrete colors would stay small (~`O(1)`), so I'd get `O(n)` performance overall. I suggest neutering to keep `n` small!

Comment: You would at best get O(KN), where K is the number of unique cat colors. The groupby solution is O(NlogN) where I'd wager that logN is going to be smaller than K in most cases. Determining the number of unique colours is going to cost more (building the set).